# Yii2 ListView from ActiveDataProvider sorted but in reversed order

Tags: php, yii2

I couldn't figure out how to render items using `ListView` in reversed order from sorted `ActiveDataProvider`.

I have table sorted by for example ID, like this:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ...
```

I take first page of 3 of them:

```
1, 2, 3
```

But I want to render it in reversed order using `ListView`, like this:

```
3, 2, 1
```

To sum up, pages should look like this:

```
3,2,1 | 6,5,4 | 9,8,7 | etc.
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reverse list of models returned by `ActiveDataProvider` by using `setModels()` and `getModels()`:

```
$dataProvider->setModels(array_reverse($dataProvider->getModels()));
echo ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    // ...
]);
```